# "Have you considered accepting..." removed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am not seeing this message anymore on Questions tab in the user page. Was it removed? It used to appear under questions that I had not accepted an answer for after certain amount of time.

To clarify I am not seeing it where it "should" be showing up, that is after enough time has passed since asking, but not too much that the message goes away.

Comment: I wonder if it was removed together with the accept rate display. This feature is one that I feel is actually worth keeping, though, since it's only shown to a user looking at their own questions.

Comment: I seem to remember it only appears after a delay and then disappears after a while. How old is the question?

Comment: If this has indeed been removed I think it should come back -- encouraging askers to give out little green checkmarks is a great way to encourage answerers to keep answering.

Comment: @ChrisF see edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We assume that once you've been around for a while, you no longer need this kind of nagging. That's why this hint is only displayed to users with less then 3000 reputation. And since you recently passed that boundary, you no longer get this message.

Comment: Is this threshold attached to the "cast close and reopen votes"? I say this because if so, in beta sites it would be 500 reputation. Also, I see some people were asking for the algorithm for this in [When is the message “Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?” displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214877/209901).