# Ability to view all questions I have asked that have answers but no accepted answers

Tags: feature-request

Just what it says.  Since on many SE sites I have less than 3,000 rep, it's good to go around once in a while and make sure I've accepted an answer if applicable (not all questions have answers where it's immediately obvious if they're correct and should be accepted in such a final way.)  Is there some way to get a list of nag-questions for all of SE?

Explanation attempt #2:  You know how, when your rep is < 3,000 on a StackExchange site, and you go to your profile, and click Questions, it says, "have you considered accepting an answer to this question?" on any question with answers but no accepted answer?  There is no way there, that I know of, to sort by this particular situation, whether a question needs an answer to be accepted or not.  Furthermore, there's no way to do it across all SE sites.  I'd like a page you can go to that would show ALL such questions of yours, needing an answer to be accepted, on ALL StackExchanges sites, at once.  This would make it easy to follow up on questions that were forgotten about due to the answer taking time to evaluate, or even questions you've answered yourself in the end, but were prevented, due to low rep, from accepting immediately (sometimes you are made to wait for two days...by then you might forget to go back and accept your own answer.)

Comment: I have no idea what your title has to do with your post.

Comment: @djechlin, not sure what I was failing to get across to you, but please see my attempt #2 in my edit.  Hopefully it's more understandable.

Comment: " You know how, when your rep is < 3,000 on a StackExchange site, and you go to your profile, and click Questions, it says, "have you considered accepting an answer to this question?" on any question with answers but no accepted answer?" <-- nope, but I do now.

Comment: How is not having 3k reputation related to your question?

Comment: @doubleDown, Apparently when your rep is higher, the question nag goes away: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166665/134550

Comment: I see. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @djechlin - I think you meant "accepted answers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search

```
answers:1 user:me hasaccepted:0 closed:no
```

(to get more keywords go to search and click "Advanced Search Tips")

You need to do this separately on each site, though.

Answer (score 1):

Data.SE should be able to help you out here.  Here's the StackOverflow version of this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/124070

You do have to run it separately for each site (IIUC), but that's a start.