# When is the message "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" displayed?

Tags: support, questions, bounties, accepted-answer

Sometimes, I notice the following message on the Questions tab in my profile on Stack Exchange site:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

When does this message get displayed? Is it based on time of non-availability of answers or inactivity period?

Answer (score 8):

It will be shown for a question if all of the following criteria are true:

- The indicator is enabled for the site (enabled on all sites minus per-site metas, Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Apps)
- You are viewing your own questions
- You have the privilege to vote down
- You do not have the privilege to cast close votes
- The question does not have an accepted answer
- The question is at least three days old and not more than 60 days old
- The question has at least one answer and is not closed
- The question does not have a currently active bounty and has not previously had a bounty

Comment: Hi animuson - do you know if [this bug](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14730/28182) is still an issue? I can't test to reproduce it myself (I'd need to create a sockpuppet and earn 125 < x < 300 rep