# What criteria will the following note be added?

Tags: discussion

When I browse the page of the list of the questions I have asked, there is a note on the side saying

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

[image]

My questions are:

1) When is this feature implemented?

2) What criteria is fulfiled to have this note showing?

Comment: Sorry, but the criteria for displaying this notice has never been clear. I did a search for this message and didn't find anything. Your question's already been asked at [When is the message "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount), but that hasn't received any answer yet.

Comment: Posting here to let you know that an employee has answered the duplicate target question.